# Remove posts from trash, add custom field to them

Tags: mysql, wordpress, function

For all my posts in the trash I need to do the following:

1) Change their status from 'trash' to 'publish'

2) Add a custom field called 'new_status' to those posts with the value 'deleted'.

Ideally I need to do with with a function that I can place in functions.php.

I think I need to start with something like this...

```
$myconversion = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status = 'publish'");
```

...but as MYSQL is not my strong point.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

luckily you don't have to know SQL, you have the powerful WP_Query function, so i think you need something like this (add this to your functions.php file)

```
function wp_update_all_posts_status($params = null){
    $args = array(
        'nopaging' => true, // Loop through all posts at once
        'post_status' => array('trash'), //Get posts "from the trash"
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            // Change the status the post to publish
            $updated = wp_update_post( array('ID' => $the_query->post->ID, 'post_status' => 'publish' ));
            //add the post "new_status" meta
            add_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'new_status', 'deleted' ); 
        }
    }
}

wp_update_all_posts_status();
```